# Bug: Getting 404 when login as different user from Manage Users. Any thoughts please?

Tags: lightning-experience, navigation

When I tried to login (by clicking Login link) as different users from Manager Users, it took me to "nowhere" which means it just results in 404 and displays the error in a polite manner.

Is this some issue in Salesforce navigation? Or did I try anything wrong? Please see the screenshot below.

**Manage Users in LEX**

[image: Manage Users in LEX]

**404 Error**

[image: 404 Error]

Comment: What is user license of related profile? Is LEX enabled for current user/profile?

Comment: @αΥβ Thanks for your reply. its a custom profile with LEX enabled. It was working fine two weeks ago without any issues. But this thing is very new and have not seen anywhere.